# Вызвать метод формы1 после закрытия формы2

Tags: c#, делегаты

Есть 2 формы Form1 и Form2. Вторая форма открывается с первой :

```
  Form2.ShowDialog();
```

После закрытия второй формы пытаюсь вызвать метод первой формы :

```
    MaterialCreate("_type")
```

Вот так:

```
    Form2.ShowDialog();
    Form2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(MaterialCreate("_type")); // ошибка
```

На что компилятор выдает ошибку : требуется имя метода. Почему так, ведь имя метода ему указал правильно ?

Comment: Покажите код метода `MaterialCreate(String)`. По идее, у Вас неправильная сигнатура метода, который Вы передаёте в делегат типа `FormClosedEventHandler`.

Comment: Сугнатура метода _MaterialCreate()_ : возвращает *void* и принимает *string _type*

Comment: А должен принимать object и FormClosedEventArgs https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.formclosedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @player one Метод  _MaterialCreate()_ должен принимать строковый аргумент иначе не будет работать.

Comment: @Сергей понимаю, но делегат FormClosedEventHandler так не думает :) В принципе klutch1991 уже написал развернутый ответ, там всё разложено.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Form2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(MaterialCreate("_type"));
```

Вы пытаетесь создать делегат типа `FormClosedEventHandler`, который в качестве агрумента ожидает метод, принимающий два параметра: `object sender` и `FormClosedEventArgs e`, а Вы вместо этого пытаетесь передать туда напрямую `MaterialCreate(String type)`. Нужно создать отдельно обработчик для события закрытия формы:

```
private void OnForm2Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
     MaterialCreate("_type");
}
```

После этого, добавьте обработчик к событию:

```
Form2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(OnForm2Closed);
```

либо более короткая запись с использованием техники "*предположение делегата*":

```
Form2.FormClosed += OnForm2Closed;
```

**UPD:**

Кроме того, можете использовать лямбда-выражение, не прибегая к созданию отдельного метода-обработчика, в таком случае просто напишите (самый простой и легко читаемый вариант):

```
Form2.FormClosed += (sender, e) => MaterialCreate("_type");
```

Comment: А что это за техника интересная _предположение делегата_ ?

Comment: https://itvdn.com/ru/video/csharp-essential/delegates